# Middleman and Phonegap issue

Tags: cordova, middleman

I'm having trouble with setting up Middleman for the past few weeks for one of my class projects.  My project use HTML 5 and will be developed for Android.  The project is on github and I cloned it on Ubuntu, and I tried to enter command "middleman build", but I got output showing that the build failed.  The output is below:

```
[WARNING] MultiJson is using the default adapter (ok_json).We recommend loading a different JSON library to improve performance.
  create  www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png
  create  www/res/screen/bada-wac/screen-type4.png
  create  www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png
  create  www/icon.png
  create  www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png
  create  www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png
  create  www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png
  create  www/res/screen/bada-wac/screen-type5.png
  create  www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png
  create  www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png
  create  www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png
  create  www/res/icon/bada-wac/icon-80-type4.png
  create  www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png
  create  www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png
  create  www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png
  create  www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png
  create  www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png
  create  www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png
  create  www/res/screen/bada/screen-portrait.png
  create  www/res/icon/tizen/icon-128.png
  create  www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-62-tile.png
  create  www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png
  create  www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png
  create  www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png
  create  www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png
  create  www/res/screen/bada-wac/screen-type3.png
  create  www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png
  create  www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png
  create  www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png
  create  www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png
  create  www/res/screen/webos/screen-64.png
  create  www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png
  create  www/res/icon/bada-wac/icon-48-type5.png
  create  www/res/icon/bada/icon-128.png
  create  www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png
  create  www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png
  create  www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png
  create  www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png
  create  www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png
  create  www/res/icon/bada-wac/icon-50-type3.png
  create  www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png
  create  www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png
  create  www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg
  create  www/app/models/user.js
  create  www/app/views/tutorial_view.js
  create  www/app/routes/application_route.js
  create  www/app/controllers/index_controller.js
  create  www/app/components/calendar.js

/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/tilt-1.3.7/lib/tilt/template.rb:118:in `require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
(in /home/javaholic/schollaborate/source/app/templates/application.handlebars)
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/tilt-1.3.7/lib/tilt/template.rb:118:in `require_template_library'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-handlebars_template-1.0.0/lib/sprockets/handlebars_template.rb:29:in `initialize_engine'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/tilt-1.3.7/lib/tilt/template.rb:56:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:196:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:196:in `evaluate'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `resolve_dependencies'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `resolve_dependencies'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/environment.rb:75:in `find_asset'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/server.rb:47:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-sprockets-3.1.4/lib/middleman-sprockets/extension.rb:244:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:65:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.1.6/lib/middleman-more/extensions/minify_javascript.rb:42:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.1.6/lib/middleman-more/extensions/minify_css.rb:48:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:49:in `_call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:30:in `request'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test.rb:230:in `process_request'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test.rb:57:in `get'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.1.6/lib/middleman-core/cli/build.rb:138:in `render_to_file'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.1.6/lib/middleman-core/cli/build.rb:280:in `execute!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.1.6/lib/middleman-core/cli/build.rb:277:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.1.6/lib/middleman-core/cli/build.rb:277:in `execute!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.1.6/lib/middleman-core/cli/build.rb:199:in `invoke!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:95:in `action'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.1.6/lib/middleman-core/cli/build.rb:64:in `build'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `__send__'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.1.6/lib/middleman-core/cli.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:29:in `__send__'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:29:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:128:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.1.6/lib/middleman-core/cli.rb:22:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/middleman-core-3.1.6/bin/middleman:18
from /usr/local/bin/middleman:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/middleman:19
```

The output that my teammate and I expected to see is that Middleman build all the web assets for phonegap and a successful build means there are no errors. So I should be able to do the ‘phonegap local run android’ and have it come up on either the emulator or the device.  However, emulator did not show up and the output was this instead:

```
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...

fs.js:427
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/javaholic/schollaborate/www/config.xml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/xml-helpers.js:107:27)
    at Object.config_parser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/config_parser.js:25:20)
    at Object.platform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:64:15)
    at LocalBuildCommand.module.exports.addPlatform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/local.build.js:153:13)
    at LocalBuildCommand.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/local.build.js:95:32)
    at LocalBuildCommand.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/local.build.js:70:10)
    at Object.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/util/command.js:28:25)
    at LocalRunCommand.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/local.run.js:68:25)
```

My phonegap version is 3.1.  I have tried bundle install and tried command “bundle exec middleman build” instead, neither did work.  I'm out of ideas on things to try, so any help/suggestions will be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.8? Middleman no longer supports Ruby 1.8. Could cause some issues. Try updating your ruby version to the latest and update all of you gems.

Comment: Both my ruby and gem version was 1.8 and I updated ruby to 1.9.3 and gem to 2.1.11.  Unfortunately it did not solve the issue (the output seems to be identical).